# Should I use ThreadPool or Task Parallel Library

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Working on a .Net Console App that processes user requests and the result of each processed request is sent back to the user (Using TCP sockets)

for testing purposes i have created a small number of threads to do the job on multiple threads, but moving to production, i am in need to be able to serve as many requests as i can in parallel.

I am confused between using ThreadPool or TPL. (The average processing time per request is 3s) Any advice?

Here is my current code:

```
 public void Start()
    {
        started = true;
        Thread looper = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BufferRunner));
        looper.Start();
        Thread looper2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BufferRunner));
        looper2.Start();
        Thread looper3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BufferRunner));
        looper3.Start();
        Thread looper4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BufferRunner));
        looper4.Start();
    }

    private void BufferRunner()
    {
        while (started)
        {
            BufferedCommand command = null;
            lock (buffer)
            {
                if (buffer.Count > 0)
                    command = buffer.Dequeue();//buffer.Enqueue happens when user request is received
            }
            if (command != null)
               ExecuteCommand(command);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always prefer the TPL over `Thread` and `ThreadPool`. Is is very rare to find a reason to use the old APIs. `Task` offers composability, better error handling and `await`.

> The average processing time per request is 3s

That sounds like the `LongRunning` option could be appropriate. Investigate that.

Comment: I implemented a version with Tasks and will be running some tests. However, Im still not sure if i should use the 'LongRunning' option or not, still learning about Tasks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use TPL because it will provide a higher level *abstraction* and better than the `ThreadPool`.